# How to solve the equation ${\log_{x} 9} + {\log_{2} x} = {\log_{2} (9+x)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function, elementary-functions

Please advise on how to solve the following equation.
$$
{\log_{x} 9} + {\log_{2} x} = {\log_{2} (9+x)}
$$
I tried to rearrange and got this.
$$
{\log_{x} 9} = {\log_{2} (1+\frac{9}{x})}
$$
$$
[{\log_{9} x}][{\log_{2} (1+\frac{9}{x})}] = 1
$$
Then I got stuck.

Anyone could help on how to proceed?

Comment: Use $log a/ log b = log_a b$

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Hint: $\ln x\ln(1+9/x)=\ln9\ln 2=\ln3\ln 4$ has two obvious roots; the hard part is checking whether it has others on $\Bbb R^+$ ([it doesn't](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+%28ln+x%29*ln%281%2B9%2Fx%29-%28ln+9%29%28ln+2%29+from+0+to+100&dataset=)).

Comment: You're right, also feel hard to find an elementary method to check, or find the bound of solutions.